# Как быстро получить thumbnail картинки?

Tags: веб-программирование, изображения, imagemagick, exif

Есть `tiff` файлы размером 1 гигабайт.
Нужно самым оптимальным способом (в плане затраты ресурсов на получение) вытащить thumbnail картинки.

Будет ли чтение exif хедеров быстрее imagemagick`a ? (по моим тестам нет но все же)

Или есть какие-то более оптимальные програмы для обработки таких больших файлов ?

Answer (score 0):

https://doc.bccnsoft.com/docs/php-docs-7-en/function.exif-thumbnail.html

exif_thumbnail — извлекает встроенные thumbnail из TIFF или JPEG изображений. Простой php скрипт с циклом решит вашу проблему.